# Spring Data elasticsearch @Query annotation for nested objects

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have two class,

```
@Document
public class PracticeQuestion {

     private int userId;
     private List<Question> questions;

// Getters and setters
}


public class Question {

     private int questionID;
     private String type;

// Getters and setters
}
```

My JSON doc is like this,

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("506d9c0ce4b005cb478c2e97"),
"userId" : 1,
"questions" : [
    {
        "questionID" : 1,
        "type" : "optional"

    },
    {
        "questionID" : 3,
        "type" : "mandatory"

    }
]
}
```

How should I write the query method to find PracticeQuestion by userId and questionID using `@Query` annotation.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to search by userId and QuestionId. You have 2 options.

1. Use nested queries (Questions in the example above is kind of a nested object and elasticsearch support search on nested objects.). You can read more about it [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html).

You can create `PracticeQuestionRepository` with a method findByUserId like shown below.

```
public interface PracticeQuestionRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<PracticeQuestion, String> {
    @Query("{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"userId":"?0"}},{"nested":{"path":"questions","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"questions.id":"?1"}}]}}}}]}}}")"
    Page<PracticeQuestion> findByUserIdAndQuestionId(String userId, String questionId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

2. If you do not want to use nested objects. De normalize the schema and flatten the question and userId at the same level and then issue a query on userId and QuestionId.

e.g.
Document 1

```
{
    "_id": "506d9c0ce4b005cb478c2e97",
    "userId": 1,
    "questionID": 1,
    "type": "optional"
}
```

Document 2

```
{
    "_id": "506d9c0ce4b005cb478c2e97",
    "userId": 1,
    "questionID": 1,
    "type": "optional"
}
```

Code for Repository

```
public interface PracticeQuestionRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<PracticeQuestion, String> {
    @Query("{"bool" : {"must" : [ {"field" : {"userId" : "?0"}}, {"field" : {"questionId" : "?1"}} ]}}"")
    Page<PracticeQuestion> findByUserIdAndQuestionId(String userId, String questionId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

[Refer this link for more examples](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.query-methods.at-query)

Comment: sorry, I have updated my question as "method to find PracticeQuestion by userId and questionID using @Query annotation".

Comment: I updated my answer based on the userId and questionId query.

Comment: Guys, sorry for using this question but it's very similar, how to do a query by Date field less than the date parameter? `Optional<List<Evento>> findByDataLessThan(LocalDateTime data);`