# Invalid custom @Query syntax Spring Elastic Search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, jhipster

Can someone shed light on this, I've followed the example here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/1.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.query-methods.at-query

...However, the syntax cannot possibly work. It results in syntax errors similar to below image. (Needless to say this does not compile)

[image]

I've attempted to escape the quotes, but the resulting `elastic` query does not work with below exception:

[image]

The thing is, other examples I've found are using the similar format and of course don't work:
[Spring Data elasticsearch @Query annotation for nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374618/spring-data-elasticsearch-query-annotation-for-nested-objects)

Any ideas?

Comment: what version of elasticsearch are you running? Check the required version of the elasticsearch data library. If I am right they depend on elastic 1.5.4 which is old. If you are running elastic 2.x, it won't work. If you upgrade to the 2.x version of spring-data elasticsearch it will be a lot better. With elastic 5 the client will have a lot less impact on the used version of the server. But is is wise to have a good look.

Comment: @JettroCoenradie just checking versions now thanks

Comment: Hmm So with Jhipster generator, and for some reason its come packaged with 1.5.2 and spring-data-elasticsearch 1.3.4... :/

Comment: The question is, what version of elasticsearch are you running? Do you have a separate elasticsearch node or are you using the embedded one?

Comment: I meant its `elasticsearch 1.5.2`, just testing now with term. Its bizaar the documenation is wrong even on the latest 2.x release doc

Comment: Not a big fan of the spring data elastic component. Did use it for a project, but for all other projects I am doing it myself. Often the elasticsearch part deviates a lot from the other model in the database for instance that for me it was a lot better not to use to much of the generated spring data stuff. But that does not help you with your problem. Val gave you the right answer :-)

Comment: Thanks @JettroCoenradie, I will certainly consider that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues:

A. The `field` query does not exist anymore, you need to use either `match` or `term` (the error message says "no query registered for [field]")

```
{"bool": {"must": {"term": {"name": "?0"}}}}
```

B. You need to escape the double quotes inside your query (as you can see your IDE is red-lining your query)

```
@Query("{\"bool\": {\"must\": {\"term\": {\"name\": \"?0\"}}}}")
```

Comment: ACK, I was just coming to that realisation based on the link in the comment you gave previously, big help, just looking into it now

Comment: Yes, that's a documentation bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: ok working perfect now with `term` instead of field and escaped double quotes cheers guys