# Is there a way to perform query_string search in elasticsearch spring boot repository

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

We are using springboot elastic search starter to get access to ElasticsearchRepository.

Earlier we would search on any field or perform [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) search in spring boot using search and query builder. This search method has been deprecated and searchSimilar has been introduced.

Any way to perform any field search on elastic search using searchSimilar method from ElasticsearchRepository with pagination ?

Comment: Found solution in link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374618/spring-data-elasticsearch-query-annotation-for-nested-objects

Comment: Please close the question if felt redundant.

Answer (score 1):

We can do query_string search query by using @Query annotation.

```
@Query("{\n" +
            "\t\"query_string\": {\n" +
            "\t  \"query\": \"?0\"\n" +
            "\t}\n" +
            "}")
    Page<Incident> findBySearchOnAllFields(String search, Pageable pageable);
```

**Note** external query object is missing as spring boot adds the same and if we add then it becomes double and won't work